# I want to convert video to jpg image

Tags: opencv, video, video-processing

I'm going to analyze video.

I want to convert video to image per sec.

I mean if the video which I want to analyze is 1 hour. The program which I want to make will make output 3600 image files.

How can I make it?

Is there any solution for it?

The worst case is that I have to run the video and take snapshot per second.

I need your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to load the video and save individual frames in a loop. This is not exactly a snapshot, but, you are just saving each and every frame.

Please mind the resolution of the video can also affect the speed in which the frames are processed.

I am going to assume you are using C++. For this, the code will look like this:

```
VideoCapture cap("Your_Video.mp4");
// Check if camera opened successfully
if(!cap.isOpened())
{
cout << "Error opening the video << endl;
return -1;
}

while(1)
{
Mat frame;
cap.read(frame);
if (frame.empty())
{
break;
}

// This is where you save the frame
imwrite( "Give your File Path", frame );

}
cap.release();
destroyAllWindows();
return 0;
}
```